# ZK ajax framework

Tags: ajax, struts, zk

Can ZK easily be integrated in a struts web application?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can find it interesting:

http://www.zkoss.org/smalltalks/zk-sample/zk-sample.html

moreover, you can browse a bit the zk forum you can find on http://www.zkoss.org/ itself, it is more than easy to find some discussion about that.
hope it can help

luca

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally struts is a full-page-post-find-action-update-full-page framework. It was written in the last century and represent one of the most successful frameworks for doing that in the last century. You can get struts to work with zk. Yet this requires downgrading how you use zk to be something of the last century. Zk is not a full page-post-framework. To have all the productivity that zk gives you have to program using event driven desktop programming patterns. It is hard to explain just how different that is without looking at code. Yet it is far more productive. This is not instant - you have to unlearn how things are normally done last century to find a better way to do things this century.

To see the difference consider exploring this sample application http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-desktop-model-view

Answer (score 1):

more concretely:
http://docs.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK/How-Tos/Integrate-Other-Frameworks#Struts_.2B_Tiles_.2B_JSP_.28.2B_Spring.29

Comment: The link is broken. Do you have the actual link?.